# nginx How to serve cached pages by nginx if site using cloudflare on proxied server goes down

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I am use Nginx Reverse proxy to serve content of site using cloudflare on proxied server.

But when proxied server goes down , pages cached by cloudflare shows

> This page () is currently offline. However, because the site uses CloudFlare's Always Online™ technology you can continue to surf a snapshot of the site. We will keep checking in the background and, as soon as the site comes back, you will automatically be served the live version. Always Online™ is powered by CloudFlare | Hide this Alert

and pages not cached by cloudflare shows

> Website is offline No cached version of this page is available.
>   Error 521

What i want is , i want to serve content cached by my nginx reverse proxy server.

How can i do so ?

my current nginx conf looks like this.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example-proxy.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        proxy_set_header CF-Connecting-IP "";
        proxy_set_header Via "$host";
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

In this case if `https://example.com/` goes down, i want to show pages cached by `nginx` and not pages cached by `cloudflare` with response code `521`

Comment: I think that [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) is a good starting point. You'll probably use `proxy_cache_use_stale` to target specific HTTP errors

Comment: @KeenanLawrence thank you, looking into it.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence looks like i can use something like proxy_cache_use_stale http_521

Comment: Cool, implement it and let us know the outcome :)

Comment: @KeenanLawrence okie., i have tried using it but i get nginx: [emerg] invalid value "http_521" in config file. looks like not all http status codes are supported for caching. any other way ? thanks

Comment: So NGINX doesn't recognise this because according to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), this HTTP code is "unassigned". I'm unsure as to whether you can add a module to NGINX to support these codes or not.